# Не делается переход по ссылке в форме. Почему?

Tags: php, wordpress

В форме, когда выставляешь галочку присутствует ссылка на страницу, когда жмёшь на ссылку - ставится почему-то галочку и меняется класс у чекбокса, но перехода никакого нет. Кто знает как можно пофиксить эту проблему? Пробовал убирать открытие в новом окне - не то, не помогает.

```
    add_filter('form_field_line','form_field_line_checkpersdata', 10, 3);
function form_field_line_checkpersdata($line, $filter, $data){
global $premiumbox;

    $type = trim(is_isset($data, 'type'));
    if($type == 'terms_personal_data'){
        $line = '
        <div class="checkpersdata_line">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="tpd" value="1" /> '. sprintf(__('I consent to processing of my personal data in accordance with Law No. 152-FZ "On Personal Data" and accept the terms and conditions of the <a href="%s" target="_blank">User Agreement</a>.','pn'), $premiumbox->get_page('terms_personal_data')) .'</label>
        </div>
        '; 
    }

    return $line;
}
```

Страница: bigpay.eu/feedback

Answer (score 0):

У Вас какой-то скрипт висит на нажатие текста. return обычно перебивает действие href.
Простейший способ обойти проверку - использовать свойство onclick (или соответствующее действие в js файле)

```
<a href="https://ya.ru" onclick="window.location='https://yandex.ru';">На Yandex, не на Ya</a>
```